# Using IF inside an Oracle trigger to change the update value

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert-update

I'm trying to change the value of the update field within an IF statement when the new value does not match the backup column value.
Can't figure it out, anybody done something like this before?

edit : I've gone thru many different versions of this, it either saves the new value anyway or causes an error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER Test_Trig
BEFORE UPDATE OF EMPID ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  backup_value table1.empid2%type;
BEGIN
  select empid2 into backup_value from table1 b where b.empid2 = :old.empid;
  if (:new.empid != empid2) then
    :new.empid := backup_value
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  `!= empid2` is wrong, because you must say whether you want the old or the new value. And why the select where you try to select the old.empid? Why not use it right away?

Comment: You cannot select from the same table in the `for each row` trigger because you'll get mutating table error. But you may just access `:old.empid2` directly, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cb1fa16ee58aa1ea0cdc200c9b057c85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as if you should utilize trigger's `when` clause (so that you'd skip `if`) and - as already commented - don't select from the same table as you'll get mutating table error.

Something like this:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table table1 as
  2  select 1 empid, 2 empid2 from dual;

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_trig
  2    before update of empid on table1
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.empid <> old.empid2)
  5  begin
  6    :new.empid := :old.empid2;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * From table1;

     EMPID     EMPID2
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL> update table1 set empid = 5;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from table1;

     EMPID     EMPID2
---------- ----------
         2          2    --> EMPID = EMPID2 = 2 because new EMPID value (5) is different 
                             from existing EMPID2 value (2)

SQL> update table1 set empid = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from table1;

     EMPID     EMPID2
---------- ----------
         2          2   --> nothing happened because EMPID is now equal to
                            EMPID2

SQL>
```

---

Because of code you suggested, `EMPID` now can't get any other value than current `EMPID2`. Maybe that's what you wanted, I can't tell.

---

**[EDIT, based on your comment]**

Maybe you'd rather raise an error (instead of *silently* setting the `EMPID` value back to its previous value).

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_trig
  2    before update of empid on table1
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.empid <> old.empid2)
  5  begin
  6    raise_application_error(-20000, 'You can not modify EMPID value. Contact AskingForAFriend');
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from table1;

     EMPID     EMPID2
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL> update table1 set empid = 5;
update table1 set empid = 5
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: You can not modify EMPID value. Contact AskingForAFriend
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TEST_TRIG", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TEST_TRIG'


SQL>
```

Comment: Let me explain the issue better, something is changing the value of empid, I made the backup column empid2, when anything tries to update empid, I want it to fail if it does not match the value in empid2. The admin page has been modified to update empid2 before it updates empid. I will eventually track down which sql or web page is doing this, but for now I just want to lock down the values in empid.

Comment: In that case, raise an error (which might help in finding out who updates those values). Have a look at edited answer.